# Using ant scriptdef regex, getting javascript.EvaluatorException

Tags: regex, ant

Environment : ANT 1.9.4, using scriptdef javascript to retrieve version number from a filename.

In a selected directory, find the file names with .jar extension, get all the file names, loop through each file name to retrieve a particular string and extract the version number from that string. I used scriptdef javascript to achieve this. Code is copied below.

File name format is 
              "GeneralService_V1.2.jar"  & 
              "GeneralService_V10.6_SSL.jar".

Regex expression used to retrieve *Vx.x* is "*\V\[0-9]+\.\[0-9]+\*" ( this is only for the second filename format).

I'm getting error -  javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: missing ; before statement (#11) in  at line number 11

Its failing at pattern line, am I using correct Pattern statement or the regex expression is wrong?

```
    <scriptdef name="jarFiles" language="javascript"> 
    <element name="fileset" type="fileset"/>            
        <![CDATA[           
            importClass(java.io.File);
            importClass(org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils);
            importClass(java.util.regex.Pattern);
            importClass(java.lang.System);
            filesets = elements.get("fileset");
              for (i = 0; i < filesets.size(); ++i) {
                fileset = filesets.get(i);                  
                Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("_\\V\\[0-9]+\\.\\[0-9]+\\_");
                Matcher matcher = pat.match(fileset);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); //prints _Vx.x_
                    String currJarVersion = matcher.group(0);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Match not found");
                }                
        ]]>
    </scriptdef> 
    <jarFiles>
        <fileset id="jars" dir="${svn.jar.path}">
              <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>  
    </jarFiles>                 

    <propertyregex property="currJarVersion"                       
                   regexp="_V"
                   replace=""
                   global="true" /> 
    <echo message="${currJarVersion}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things wrong with this code...  Firstly, you've declared it to be JavaScript but you're using Java constructs like typed variable declarations (`Pattern pat = ...`) which JavaScript does not allow.  Secondly, the regular expression is wrong, you've got too many things backslash-escaped.  Thirdly, the method to create a `Matcher` from a `Pattern` is called `matcher`, not `match`.  Fourthly, you can't apply a regular expression to a `FileSet` like this, you would need to extract the list of file names that the `FileSet` matches and then apply the regular expression to each of those in turn.  And finally that's not how you set Ant properties from a script.

I would suggest abandoning `scriptdef` altogether as you can do the mapping far more simply with native Ant facilities such as `pathconvert`

```
<pathconvert pathsep="&#10;" property="currJarVersion">
  <fileset dir="${svn.jar.path}">
    <include name="**/*.jar" />
  </fileset>
  <regexpmapper from="^.*_V([0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*$$" to="\1" /><!-- $ doubled for Ant -->
</pathconvert>
```

Comment: This is the first time I've come across pathconvert, it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @Lola Glad it helped, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that when you get an answer that solves your problem it's good manners to _accept_ by clicking on the tick mark to the left. This shows other readers at a glance that the problem is solved (and it also gives both the asker and answerer a reputation bonus).

Comment: Sorry, new to this site, I clicked on the tick mark. Thanks again.